# Property attributes is missing in interface declaration

Tags: typescript

I have a list of nodes, which I have declare as

```
const node7 = { value: -50000, next: undefined };
const node6 = { value: 5, next: node7 };
const node5 = { value: 9, next: node6 };
const node4 = { value: 1, next: node5 };
const node3 = { value: -16, next: node4 };
const node2 = { value: 36, next: node3 };
const node1 = { value: 3, next: node2 };
const head = { value: 16, next: node1 };
```

I created an interface like

```
interface Node {
  value: number,
  next: Node | undefined
}
```

And my method looks like

```
function shortList(head: Node){
  ...
}
```

Typescript is complaining that

```
Argument of type '{ value: number; next: { value: number; next: { value: number; next: { value: number; next: { val...' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Node'.
  Property 'attributes' is missing in type '{ value: number; next: { value: number; next: { value: number; next: { value: number; next: { val...
```

**What I am doing wrong?**

Comment: You haven't posted the part of the code that actually generates the error. My guess is that you're getting this error because you're using the name `Node` which is [an existing type](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/lib/lib.d.ts#L12528) already. Try to rename your type to something else.

Comment: Nico, it really doesn't matter anymore. We allow both commas and semicolons, so that's stylistic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a global type named `Node` that refers to the DOM's Node.

That interface of yours is actually *merging* with that global declaration of `Node`. What you will need to do is either

- Export it so that the containing file becomes a module, and your `Node` doesn't merge with the global `Node`.
- Rename it entirely (e.g. `MyNode`)

### Future advice

Sorry about the confusion there! Something that would have hinted at this was if you tried finding all references to `Node` in your editor. Beyond that, this is something you really do need to read up about to know about the language.